# How to replicate Query::notMatching() in CakePHP 3.0?

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I don't like to use cakephp 3.1 beta. I'm using version 3.0. I'm trying to find all posts that doesn't have a specific tag. How can I do this?

Comment: If you're asking how you can find specific Stack Overflow posts, that is a question for Stack Overflow Meta.

Comment: @m69 I'm asking how can I find a post in a cakephp project

Comment: Then I misread the question. Please ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to replicate the behavior of `notMatching()`, you'll have to add an appropriate `LEFT` join with conditions to match the tags that should be excluded, another `LEFT` join to include the join table, and then use conditions on the main query that exlcude rows with matching tags via a `IS NULL` check on the join tables primary key.

Here's a basic example, assuming a `Posts belongsToMany Tags` relation

```
$query = $Posts
    ->find()
    ->leftJoin(
        ['Tags' => 'tags'],
        ['Tags.title' => 'specificTagToExlcude']
    )
    ->leftJoin(
        ['PostsTags' => 'posts_tags'],
        'Posts.id = PostsTags.post_id AND Tags.id = PostsTags.tag_id'
    )
    ->where([
        'PostsTags.id IS NULL'
    ]);
```

This would create a query similar to

```
SELECT
    Posts.id AS `Posts__id`,
    // ...
FROM
    posts Posts 
LEFT JOIN
    tags Tags 
        ON Tags.title = 'specificTagToExlcude' 
LEFT JOIN
    posts_tags PostsTags
        ON PostsTags.post_id = Posts.id 
        AND PostsTags.tag_id = Tags.id 
WHERE
    PostsTags.id IS NULL
```